# Неожиданное завершения работы Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, macos, браузер, macbook

- Ошибка во время запуска Google Chrome (Для macOS 10.13 - Версия
  106.0.5249.119 (Официальная сборка), (x86_64)) Ошибки возникают после перезагрузки macOS или отключения и включения MacBook Данные ошибки
  устраняются только в одном случае, полного удаления Google Chrome и
  установкой заново, затем после последующей перезагрузки системы
  Google Chrome не запускается.

  Аппаратное обеспечение:

  Название модели: MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2011)   Идентификатор
  модели: MacBookPro 8.2   Имя процессора: Quad-Core Intel Core i7
  Скорость процессора: 2,2 GHz   Количество процессоров: 1   Общее
  количество ядер: 4   Кэш 2-го уровня (в каждом ядре): 256 КБ   Кэш
  3-го уровня: 6 МБ   Технология Hyper-Threading: Включен   Память: 8
  ГБ   Версия Boot ROM: MBP81.0050.B00   Версия SMC (система): 1.69f4

  Обзор системного ПО:

  Версия системы: macOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H15)     Версия Kernel:
  Darwin 19.6.0

  Process:               Google Chrome [629]
  Path:                  /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
  Identifier:            com.google.Chrome
  Version:               ???
  Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
  Parent Process:        ??? [1]
  Responsible:           Google Chrome [629]
  User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2022-10-25 14:11:47.678 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.7 (19H15)
Report Version:        12

Time Awake Since Boot: 1200 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x1

kernel messages:

### VM Regions Near 0 (cr2):

```
__TEXT                 00000001049ab000-00000001049e1000 [  216K] r-x/r-x SM=COW
```

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   ???                           0x0000000109fa5000 _dyld_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x00007ffeeb254c20
r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
rip: 0x0000000109fa5000  rfl: 0x0000000000000200  cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     0

Binary Images:
0x1049ab000 -        0x1049e0217 +??? (???) <4C4C44D4-5555-3144-A19F-E8B5D30BD2C5> (null)
0x109fa4000 -        0x10a035f47 +??? (750.6) <1D318D60-C9B0-3511-BE9C-82AFD2EF930D> (null)

External Modification Summary:
Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
task_for_pid: 7
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by this process:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by all processes on this machine:
task_for_pid: 60910
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1052K resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1052K(100%)
Writable regions: Total=8408K written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=8408K(100%)

```
                            VIRTUAL   REGION
```

REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced)
===========                     =======  =======
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        1
Stack                             8192K        1
__DATA                             232K        4
__DATA_CONST                        20K        1
__LINKEDIT                         256K        3
__TEXT                             800K        2
shared memory                        8K        2
===========                     =======  =======
TOTAL                             65.3M       14

Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0050.B00, 4 processors, Quad-Core Intel Core i7, 2,2 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.69f4
Graphics: kHW_IntelHD3000Item, Intel HD Graphics 3000, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D543435315336424D5238432D48392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x02B5, -
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.102.31)
Bluetooth: Version 7.0.6f7, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: KINGSTON SUV400S37240G, 240,06 GB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.1

Comment: ну так firefox гораздо лучше браузер))

Comment: к сожалению или к счастью им не пользуюсь)